# What is the best way to decorate methods of a Python class?

Tags: python, methods, decorator

I am following below conventions to decorate certain methods in a Python class. I am wondering if there are some better ways to do the same. My approach certainly doesn't look good; the call to original member function doesn't look intuitive at all.

```
from threading import Lock

def decobj(fun):
    def fun2(*args, **kwards):
        with args[0].lock:
            print 'Got the lock'
            fun(*args, **kwards)
    return fun2

class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.lock = Lock()
        self.x = a
        pass

    @decobj
    def fun(self, x, y):
        print self.x, x, y


a = A(100)
a.fun(1,2)
```

Comment: *Why* do you feel your approach doesn't look good? If you are only ever decorating methods, why not just add `self` to the wrapper signature?

Comment: @MartijnPieters the call to original member function doesn't look intuitive at all. So, I think there will be some better way.

Comment: It looks fine if you're comfortable with Python's unary `*` and `**` operators. Some constructs just look odd until you use them a few times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your decorator can only work on methods (because you need access to the instance-specific lock) then just include `self` in the wrapper signature:

```
from functools import wraps

def decobj(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwards):
        with self.lock:
            print 'Got the lock'
            func(self, *args, **kwards)
    return wrapper
```

I included the [`@functools.wraps()` utility decorator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps); it'll copy across various pieces of metadata from the original wrapped function to the wrapper. This is invariably a good idea.